# color points based on a variable (base R)

Tags: r, colors, points

I'm making a map in base R where I'd like to color points based on a variable (Lygodium_data$make.library.) in the dataset. Lygodium_data$make.library. is a numeric variable (1 or 2).  This doesn't work:

```
col.list <- c("black", "red")
palette(col.list)
map("world", xlim=c(-105, -70), ylim=c(18, 40), col="black")
map.axes(cex.axis=.375)
map("state", add=TRUE, lwd=1, col="black")
points(Lygodium_data$provided.longitude, Lygodium_data$provided.latitude,
       col = Lygodium_data$make.library., cex = .5, pch = 16)
```

I get the error: Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) :
invalid color name ''

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
James

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that base requires the categorical variables to be factors when assigning colors:

```
plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, col = iris$Species)
# works fine

plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Width, col = as.character(iris$Species))
# Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid color name 'setosa'
```